# [UIImage size]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8452560

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation

i dont known why my app get bug when i try to rotate image in the second time

```
-(UIImage *)rotateImage:(UIImage *)image{
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    CGSize rotatedSize = image.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(90));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-image.size.width / 2, -image.size.height / 2, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

and i call this function by :

```
 NSLog(@"%f %f",rotatedOriginImage.size.width,rotatedOriginImage.size.height);
    rotatedOriginImage = [self rotateImage:rotatedOriginImage];
```

at the first time it log :

```
2012-07-11 17:22:50.825 meshtiles[3330:707] 600.000000 600.000000
```

but at the second times:

```
2012-07-11 17:22:55.253 meshtiles[3330:707] *** -[UIImage size]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8452560
```

any support for this case, please help me

Comment: You'll need to show us where you get `rotatedOriginImage` from. The problem doesn't lie in the `-rotateImage:` method, the problem is that the object you give it has been overreleased.

Comment: What do you mean by first time and second time.Is it that before rotation and after rotation? You have to check for your rotatedOriginImage.Is it released somewhere in the code?

Comment: "rotatedOriginImage" is set after the method "rotateImage" is called and return the image. And you are accessing its size before setting it. NSLog statement should be after line where the "rotateImage" method is called.

Comment: @joerick If he isn't using ARC, then the problem does lie in the `rotateImage:` method.

Comment: @NickBull, I don't think that's right. No rules of memory management have been broken in the `-rotateImage:` method. The function returns an autoreleased UIImage object, as you would expect from the method name. The problem must therefore be outside the method.

Comment: Perhaps @Makio is storing the returned image into an instance variable? In this case, you'd see a problem. Try declaring `rotatedOriginImage` as a property `@property (retain) UIImage * rotatedOriginImage;` and accessing it using `self.rotatedOriginImage`...

Comment: @joerick Sorry, I meant to say the problem is *linked* to the `rotateImage:` method. You are correct that it's returning an autoreleased object, but it isn't being retained in his call (see my answer below). Sorry for the slight confusion there.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using ARC, then you are returning an autoreleased object `newImage` from your method. You need to retain it when you get it back.

`rotatedOriginImage = [[self rotateImage:rotatedOriginImage] retain];`

But then you will have to remember to release it as well after you have called rotateImage. so you will need to change your code to do that

Comment: thanks alot about your support, only add retain at the end, really magic, thanks alot

Comment: @Makio If you haven't added in a release as well, then you are going to be over-retaining and leaking memory.